# Multiple crontabs needed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, raspbian

So I have looked for a solution to this everywhere and I never got an answer.

How do I make multiple crontabs? I currently am running scripts that interfere and I am 110% sure that if I am able to run multiple crontabs that I will solve this issue. (Yeah I tried everything).
Can I perhaps make multiple users that each have their own crontab? And will those crontabs run at the same time?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you so sure that multiple crontabs will solve the issue? I think your real problem is that the scripts interfere with each other; you might update your question (or post a new one) to ask about that.

Answer (score 0):

There's no exclusivity inherent in multiple crontabs.  If two separate crontabs each say to run a script every Monday at 4am, then cron will run both scripts more or less at the same time, on Mondays at 4am.

At a guess, you need locking, so that only one or the other of your interfering scripts runs at a time. `flock(1)` is a very convenient tool for use in shell scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3> /path/to/lock
flock 3

# something useful here

exit 0  # releases lock
```

The above acquires an advisory lock, or waits until the lock is freed and then acquires it.  To try only once without waiting, you can do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3> /path/to/lock
flock -n 3 || exit 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply this is going the right way :).

Comment: I have two scripts (a pair) that I need to run for them to upload to one fb page. Now if I want to have another page automated too I need to have another pair of those scripts. When I put one of the pair in cronjobs it works perfect but if I put more than a pair it it wont work good. Can I lock in a specific job (a pair)? Like isolate them?

Comment: The lock is associated with a file, so you can use different files to have separate locks for separately coordinated scripts.  I might be misunderstanding your question - if you want to post some examples, it might help.

Comment: Sure! So basically there are two scripts that work with each other to do one job. So if I want to post to three pages I have 6 scripts in total.

Comment: So if I'm locking a script then I don't think it would help since there is another script needed. Maybe theres a way to run those two scripts as one job and lock them like a job? Like giving them a name such as job1 and then the second pair of scripts, lock them in as a job then name it job2? Maybe?

Comment: You could wrap the calls to the two scripts in a third and put the lock in the third.  Have you  considered combining the two scripts into a single script?